# Control the inclinometer with RS232 or UART

Tags: gpio, python, serial, uart

I have bought an inclinometer today to try some things.

Inclinometer has two communication port; RS232 and UART.

Which one should I select? Actually I tried both but none of them worked.

I have followed all the instructions on this page : http://elinux.org/RPi_Serial_Connection#Connection_to_a_microcontroller_or_other_peripheral

I have tried both with minicom and this small python script:

```
import serial
import time

port = serial.Serial(
    port='/dev/ttyAMA0',
    baudrate=38400,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    interCharTimeout=0.1,
    timeout=1
)
print("Port Name: %s" % port.name)

while True:
    port.write(bytes("get---x", 'iso-8859-1'))
    rcv = port.read(10)
    print(rcv)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

[**Datasheet**](http://www.leveldevelopments.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/documents/LCP-45_Dual_Axis_Inclinometer_PCB.pdf) is here

I have tried both of the connections, on the picture it's connected to rs232 port.
[image: connection]

I have followed this page when I connecting the inclinometer;

http://elinux.org/RPi_Low-level_peripherals#Model_A.2B.2C_B.2B_and_B2

- pin1: (Red) +ve Supply 3.3V
- pin6: (Black) Ground (0V)
- pin8: (Green) UART Tx
- pin10: (Yellow) UART Rx

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: The pins used appear correct.  Could you confirm you have connected one ends TX to the other ends RX and vice versa?

Comment: OMG, you are right... What a big mistake. Should I use UART port of the inclinometer right?

Comment: You may be too late.  I just looked at the inclinometer datasheet.  You must use the UART connections pins 5 and 6 on the inclinometer to connect to the Pi's UART.  Using RS232 may destroy the Pi's gpios or the Pi.